# Update many-to-many counter cache for multiple rows and all their parents in 1 query

Tags: mysql, many-to-many

Consider a blog application which has tables for  posts, categories and a lookup table linking a post with one or more categories. Categories are hierarchical. Posts can be assigned to any category, not just leaf nodes.

The categories table has a `post_count` field which caches the number of posts assigned to the specific category. It also has `parent_id`, `lft` and `rght` columns for MPTT.

But it also has a `under_post_count` field which caches the number of distinct posts assigned to it or any of it's child categories. This is useful so you can **display a hierarchical list of categories with the number of posts assigned to it, *or one of its children*, next to it**.

My application has got to the point where after a post is created with categories, or it's categories are edited or one which had categories is deleted, I have a list of category IDs of the old and new categories, whose `post_count` field needs updating. What I was hoping I could do next is in a single query, **update the `under_post_count` fields for all those categories identified, and all their parents, with the number of distinct posts assigned to each category or any of it's children**.

Here's the SQL required to create the tables and some test data for categories:

```
CREATE TABLE `categories` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `parent_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `lft` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `rght` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `post_count` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `under_post_count` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM;

CREATE TABLE `categories_posts` (
  `category_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `post_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`category_id`,`post_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM;

INSERT INTO `categories` (`id`, `parent_id`, `lft`, `rght`, `name`) VALUES
(1, NULL, 1, 8, 'Cat 1'),
(4, 1, 2, 3, 'Cat 1.1'),
(5, 1, 4, 5, 'Cat 1.2'),
(6, 1, 6, 7, 'Cat 1.3'),
(2, NULL, 9, 16, 'Cat 2'),
(7, 2, 10, 11, 'Cat 2.1'),
(8, 2, 12, 13, 'Cat 2.2'),
(9, 2, 14, 15, 'Cat 2.3'),
(3, NULL, 17, 24, 'Cat 3'),
(10, 3, 18, 19, 'Cat 3.1'),
(11, 3, 20, 21, 'Cat 3.2'),
(12, 3, 22, 23, 'Cat 3.3');
```

Run this a few times to create some test data for the `categories_posts` table:

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO `categories_posts` (`category_id`, `post_id`) 
SELECT `id`, CEILING(10 * RAND()) FROM `categories` ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 6
```

Can anyone figure this out, your help would be much appreciated?

Comment: +1 for well defined question with good DDL and sample data

Answer (score 3, accepted):

well there are a few ways to skin a cat here (assuming 5.1 and triggers)

- you can update everything from application layer
- you can trigger updates to `post_count` from `categories_posts` and trigger updates (cascade) to `under_post_count` from `categories`
- finally, you can trigger all updates from `categories_posts`

Also depending on the actual number of categories, you might not need to denormalize `under_post_count` as it should be rather easy and inexpensive to fetch it with

```
SELECT c.id, SUM(cc.post_count) 
FROM categories c 
LEFT JOIN categories cc ON c.lft <= cc.lft AND c.rght >= cc.rght 
GROUP BY c.id;
```

Fetching the actual counts on exact match is

```
SELECT c.id, COUNT(*) 
FROM categories c 
LEFT JOIN categories_posts cp ON c.id = cp.post_id 
GROUP BY c.id;
```

Combining the two gives the counts including the hierarchies

```
SELECT c.id, COUNT(*) 
FROM categories c 
LEFT JOIN categories cc ON c.lft <= cc.lft AND c.rght >= cc.rght 
LEFT JOIN categories_posts cp ON cc.id = cp.post_id
GROUP BY c.id;
```

**EDIT**

Constructing update statements from the above should not be so hard

```
UPDATE categories 
SET post_count = (SELECT COUNT(*) 
                  FROM categories_posts cp 
                  WHERE cp.post_id = categories.id)
```

should work for the `post_count`

Situation for the `under_post_count` is different since mysql does not like to hear that target table is mentioned in the where part, therefore you have to do some monstrosity like this

```
UPDATE categories LEFT JOIN 
       (SELECT c.id, COUNT(*) AS result 
        FROM categories c 
        LEFT JOIN categories cc ON c.lft <= cc.lft AND c.rght >= cc.rght 
        INNER JOIN categories_posts cp ON cc.id = cp.post_id
        GROUP BY c.id) AS x ON categories.id = x.id
SET under_post_count = x.result
```

**EDIT2**
Actually there is an error in all of the above queries - whenever I joined categories and posts I should have joined on `cc.id = cp.category_id` and not `cp.post_id`, which then I didn't check. Don't feel like correcting... but only in this last query

```
UPDATE categories LEFT JOIN 
       (SELECT c.id, COUNT(*) AS result 
        FROM categories c 
        LEFT JOIN categories cc ON c.lft <= cc.lft AND c.rght >= cc.rght 
        INNER JOIN categories_posts cp ON cc.id = cp.category_id
        INNER JOIN posts p ON cp.post_id = p.id
        WHERE p.status = 'published'
        GROUP BY c.id) AS x ON categories.id = x.id
SET under_post_count = x.result,
    post_count = (SELECT COUNT(*) 
                  FROM categories_posts cp 
                  WHERE cp.category_id = categories.id)
```

**EDIT3**
Just few notes:

- the above query will fix the `under_post_count` and `post_count` regardless of the state of the data,
- there are queries that are cheaper which if you data access layers are properly abstracted, secured and if you can assure the atomicity - these queries would only do `post_count = post_count +/- 1` on appropriate records in statuses (similary for `under_post_count`),
- in case you can not reliably emulate triggers from application level it might still be cheaper to check if you need to run the above queries (even though mysql is quite good in this respect, but if you want to be DB agnostic), or adopt some strategy that you normally just increment/decrement the counters and only periodically recalculate the number.

Comment: @Unreason, thanks for your reply, sorry I didn't specify in the question, but is there a way to do this without relying on triggers? I.e. purely in an SQL UPDATE statement?

Comment: @neilcrookes, I updated the question with the UPDATE statements. You should be able to join them together. The performance will not be great. May I ask why not triggers?

Comment: @Unreason, brilliant, many thanks. One last question (promise): how would I also add a scope condition on the posts table, e.g. posts.status = 'published'?

Comment: @neilcrookes, updated - there was an error which propagated through all queries. Btw, you did not answer - why not triggers? Usually it is better that database maintain your data integrity, then to do it on application level.

Comment: @Unreason, perfect, many many thanks. The reason for no triggers is this query will actually be implemented by the ORM layer in my application which is dbms agnostic. Furthermore, the query is being built in a component of the application that can be applied to any data with this kind of relationship.

Comment: @Unreason, one more question, sorry, I lied before ;-), at the point when I run this query I know the ids of the categories the post was and is now assigned to (but not their parents), is there a way to restrict the update to just those categories and their parents, as opposed updating every single category?

Comment: @Unreason, I just noticed the under_post_count is not a count of the distinct posts. Do you have any ideas for fixing it? Your help is much appreciated.

Comment: @neilcrookes, well I'd fix it, but not sure what is the problem. Can you edit the random sample with real sample and then post expected results, only to illustrate.

Comment: @Unreason the problem is that currently the under_post_count is a count of all combinations of post and category that are assigned to a category or any of it's children, but a post assigned to cat 1 and cat 1.1 should only be counted once in the under_post_count field on cat 1. Imagine a nested list of categories on a blog, and next to the category name, in brackets, is the number of posts assigned to that category or any of it's children, and if you click on the category name, you see the list of posts that are assigned to that category or any of it's children, does that make sense?

Comment: @neilcrookes, yes I think I get what you mean. If I understand you correctly all is fine with `post_count`. If you want to count distinct IDs, just put that instead of the `COUNT(*)` -> `COUNT(DISTINCT post_id)`. This will (of course) make the query perform even worse :)

Comment: @neilcrookes, basically what you are saying is that if among the tags for a post there are any tags that are in ancestor-descendant relationship then for the purposes of the hierarchical count you can ignore the ancestor tag (as it will be already increased by counting the descendant)?